# Calculate location, relying on small movements, of Android phone, in Kotlin, to simulate a butterfly net

Tags: android, accelerometer

In Kotlin I am working on a program where the user moves their phone to control a virtual butterfly net.  The positional information is sent to an `MQTT broker` and the UI application will get the data.

My problem is accurately showing the position.  If the phone is the net part of the catcher, then ideally as you move the phone, using the accelerometer I should know which direction you are moving, and can send that data.

Nice in theory, harder in practice.

To cut down on code, I just want to know how much the phone moves up, realizing that at most it will move two or three feet up, so if it moves six inches, I want to tell the UI that it moved up six inches.

I am trying to adjust based on the orientation of the phone, in the beginning section.

How do I accurately track the positional information?

```
override fun onSensorChanged(sensorEvent: SensorEvent?) {
    val mySensor = sensorEvent!!.sensor

     if (mySensor.type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        var mSensorZ: Float= 0F
        when (mDisplay?.getRotation()) {
            Surface.ROTATION_0 -> {
                mSensorZ = sensorEvent.values[2];
            }
            Surface.ROTATION_90 -> {
                mSensorZ = sensorEvent.values[2];
            }
            Surface.ROTATION_180 -> {
                mSensorZ = sensorEvent.values[2];
            }
            Surface.ROTATION_270 -> {
                mSensorZ = sensorEvent.values[2];
            }
        }
         val alpha = 0.8;

        var gravity = DoubleArray(3)
        var linear_acceleration = DoubleArray(3)
        // Isolate the force of gravity with the low-pass filter.
        gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * sensorEvent.values[2];

        // Remove the gravity contribution with the high-pass filter.
        linear_acceleration[2] = sensorEvent.values[2] - gravity[2];
        // Limit to 3 significant figures, rather than using BigDecimal
        val nz = (((mSensorZ - gravity[2]) * 1000).toInt() / 1000).toFloat()
        if(Math.abs(lz - nz) > 0.3) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Moved z " + (lz - nz))
            // This may be the wrong direction, don't care as long as it is roughly accurate on amount 
            val payload: String = if (lx1 - nz < 0) Operator.Right.toString() + (12 * (lz1 - nz)).toString() else Operator.Up.toString() + (12 * (lz1 - nz)).toString
            try {
                val encodedPayload = payload.toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset())
                val message = MqttMessage(encodedPayload)
                val r = client?.publish(topic, message);
                Log.d(TAG, "**** mqtt: ${payload}")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        lz = nz
```

Comment: Realize that if the user moves the device slowly it will be within noise margin levels of the accelerometer. Have you considered using ARCore? Found this informative post regarding ARKit: https://medium.com/super-ventures-blog/why-is-arkit-better-than-the-alternatives-af8871889d6a

Comment: Hi @MorrisonChang, actually I am leaning toward that way, as I think what I am trying to do isn't possible, or is hard.  I am going to see if I can train a neural network to recognize position by using a camera on a raspberry pi.

Comment: I think you should remove [tag:kotlin] as I don't think it's really relevant to your question. Yes, you are using this language, but your problem isn't with Kotlin, you are trying to find the right algorithm. If anything, [tag:Java] would be more relevant as Android libraries are Java based with more people working in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION which handles removing the gravity. This will give you accurate values. Also try using any unity plugins that have world value mappings, that will map correctly to your calculated values.